# Displaylink USB video adapter not working under Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: video, usb, graphics-card, display, ubuntu-10.10

I just bought [this USB graphics adapter](http://www.hi-techitaly.com/news/computer/2501-bestit-itek-uga-connettere-fino-a-6-monitor-allo-stesso-computer.html) and I need to use it on Ubuntu 10.10. I followed [this guide](http://libdlo.freedesktop.org/wiki/), but when I ran

```
$ ./configure && sudo make install && make check
```

nothing happened. On Windows, after the installation the monitor was detected automatically.

How do I get it to work on Ubuntu?